# Retrieve All MySQL/MariaDB Table Definition From .frm Files

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ddl, metadata

I wonder if it is possible to retrieve the MySQL/MariaDB table definitions from the `.frm` files?

For example, if I wanted to steal your database and I had access to your MySQL/MariaDB files but didn't have its user account, could I copy all the `.frm` files from your database, paste them into my own server and then run `mysqldump --no-data` to retrieve the exact DDL?

Next if the answer is **yes**:

- Does it apply to different server versions and/or OS?
- What can I do to prevent or make it difficult for people to do this with my database?

Next if the answer is **no**:

- Is there any dependency to other file? Or would I have to do something?
- What exactly is the role of the `.frm` files?

Answer (score 1):

A 'partial' Answer...

The `.frm` contains, in an encoded format, the `CREATE TABLE` for the one table.

Copying a `.frm` into your copy of MySQL would, in theory, give you the schema definition.  But, other info is needed.  So, now the challenge is to try to re-establish a table where the data is lost, but the schema is still in the .frm.  MyISAM depends on the existence of a `.MYD` (`.MYI` can be reconstructed); InnoDB has some hooks in `ibdata1`, but these may be reconstructable.  (Hence, this Answer is only 'partial'.)

`.frm` files are probably binary compatible between OS versions, even big-endian vs little-endian.  And across large swaths of MySQL/MariaDB versions.  A table with a `JSON` column would not be backward compatible.  There have been only a few other incompatible changes in the past decade.

As for hacking into your system.  Which is easier to get into -- The filesystem, or MySQL?  The .frm file is somewhat protected by directory and file permissions.  MySQL is somewhat protected by its password mechanism.  Obviously, you should do whatever you can to prevent access to both.

A common entry point into MySQL is via web arguments (`<form>s` in HTML) where the values are not properly escaped before `INSERTing` text into the database.  There are different solutions to that entrypoint, depending on which API is used.  (I've seem a hacker post `/etc/passwd` on the Internet; he got it from a PHP program that failed to escape simple data entry fields.)  See "SQL Injection".

Is your schema the most valuable thing?  I would expect the data to be more important.  And also the `root` password for your server.